# Checkbox.checked is not working in View Monodroid

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, xamarin

I am new to mono for android. I am trying to make a simple checkbox list where I can select my candidates, press a button to insert them to Database. All is fine till here but the problem is with loading my checked values. My checkboxes are always unchecked even if i explicitly put **this.Checked = true;**

here is my code:

**Loading listview:**

```
    var CandidatesList = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.lstVotingCandidates);
    CandidatesVoteAdapter cva = new CandidatesVoteAdapter(this, MAE.Code.Utilities.CandidatesInfo.CurrentList);
    CandidatesList.ChoiceMode = ChoiceMode.Multiple;
    CandidatesList.Adapter = cva;
```

**Adapter:**

```
public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View view = convertView; // re-use an existing view, if one is available
    if (view == null) // otherwise create a new one
    {  
       view = new Views.CandidateVoteItemView(context, items[position]);
    }
    return view;
}
```

**View:**

```
class CandidateVoteItemView : CheckBox
{
    public MAE.MAEService.Candidate Candidate { get; protected set; }
    public CandidateVoteItemView(Context context, MAE.MAEService.Candidate candidate) : base(context)
    {
        this.Text = candidate.FirstName;                                 //Working 
        this.Checked = true;// (candidate.isChecked == 1) ? true : false;//Not Working
    }
}
```

Comment: You can try this approach: lv.SetItemChecked(1, true);

[Taken from official xamarin site](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/working_with_listviews_and_adapters/part_3_-_customizing_a_listview%27s_appearance) and check section 2.2

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it did the job even though it should work the way I was doing it first since my view is just a checkbox. Anyway thanks a lot

Comment: @jHogen please post it as an answer so OP can accept it so you both get points.

Comment: @Cheesebaron Thanks for the tip, added the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this approach:

```
lv.SetItemChecked(1, true);
```

[Taken from official xamarin site](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/working_with_listviews_and_adapters/part_3_-_customizing_a_listview%27s_appearance) and check section 2.2